# Calculation of quadratic covariation of stopped processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am stuck in computing the quadratic covariation of the following two processes:

Let $0< y <r$ and let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion started at $y$.

Let $T_0 = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : B_t = 0 \}$ and let $T_r = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : B_t = r \}$. Also, set $Z_t= B_{T_0 \wedge T_r \wedge t}$. How can we prove that

> $$ d  \langle Z, B \rangle_t = \mathbf{1}_{ \{t \leq T_r\} } \frac{Z_t}{B_t} dt \quad \quad ?$$

Comment: Do you know Itô's formula?

Comment: Yes. But do you mean Ito product rule?

Comment: @saz Frankly speaking, I haven't seen Ito's formula being applied to a covariation process.

Comment: I don't want you to apply Itô's formula to the covariation process, but to the process $(Z_t,B_t)$. Note that $A_t := \langle Z,B \rangle_t$ is the unique (increasing suitable measurable) process such that $Z_t B_t -A_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: @saz But I have only learnt Ito's formula being applied to a real-valued process (i.e. $F(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, where $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are semimartingales and $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function.).

Comment: So what? $Z$ and $B$ are both (semi)martingales.

Comment: @saz Do you actually mean applying Ito's formula to $Z_tB_t$?

Comment: Well, I want you to apply Itô's formula for $F(x,y) := x \cdot y$ and the process $(Z,B)$

Comment: @saz  Yes, so that is Ito's product rule ( which is actually used to prove Ito's formula.) But then rearranging terms, we get $d \langle B, Z \rangle_t = d(Z_t B_t) - Z_t dB_t - B_t dZ_t$, which makes the problem even harder, as we are computing stochastic integrals.

Comment: Depends on the proof (and to have an extra name for this simple product rule seems superfluous to me, but okay). So what do you know about stochastic integrals? Ever heard of the fact that stochastic integrals (with respect to martingales) are martingales?

Comment: @saz Yes. So this tells us that $\int Z \,dB$ and $\int B \,dZ$ are martingales. I also know that $\int B \,dZ = (\int B\, dB)^{T_0 \wedge T_r}$. But I don't know whether that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Lemma: Let $f,g \in L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{P})$ be progressively measurable. Then for all $t \leq T$ $$\langle \int_0^{\cdot} f(s) \, dB_s, \int_0^{\cdot} g(s) \, dB_s \rangle_t = \int_0^t f(s) g(s) \, ds.$$

Proof: We know that the claim holds true for $f=g$. Now, using $$ xy = \frac{1}{4} ((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2),$$ we get $$\begin{align*} &\quad \int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s \cdot \int_0^t g(s) \, dB_s - \int_0^t f(s) g(s)\\ &= \frac{1}{4} \left( \int_0^t (f+g)^2 \, dB_s - \int_0^t (f+g)^2(s) \, ds \right) - \frac{1}{4} \left( \int_0^t (f-g)^2 \, dB_s - \int_0^t (f-g)^2(s) \, ds \right). \end{align*}$$ Since both terms on the right-hand side are martingales, the left-hand side is also a martingale and this finishes the proof.

---

**Hint:** Find suitable $f$, $g$ and apply the above lemma.

---

> Solution: $f=1$, $g(s)= 1_{\{s \leq T_0 \wedge T_R\}}$, then $$\begin{align*} \langle Z,B \rangle_t &\stackrel{\text{Lemma}}{=} \int_0^t 1_{\{s \leq T_0 \wedge T_R\}} \, ds = \int_0^t 1_{\{s \leq T_r\}} \underbrace{1_{\{s \leq T_0\}}}_{\frac{Z_t}{B_t}} , ds. \end{align*}$$

Comment: I am still confused why $T_0$ is not present in the above expression on the right hand side.

Comment: @erik Actually, it is present on the right-hand side (mind that $Z_{T_0}=0$ if $T_0<T_r$). What do you get if you apply the above lemma?

Comment: Are you suggesting to plug $f$ as $B$ and $g$ as $Z$? But it doesn't seem to work? I really don't know how to get the indicator function.

Comment: @erik No, that's not what I want you to do. Find $f$, $g$ such that $$B_t = \int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$ and $$Z_t = \int_0^t g(s) \, dB_s.$$

Comment: so $f=1$ and $g= \mathbf{1}_{ \{T \leq T_0 \wedge T_R\} }$?

Comment: @erik $1_{\{T \leq T_0 \wedge T_R\}}$ doesn't make sense (because the variable of integration is $s$), but I guess you mean $$g(s) = 1_{\{s \leq T_0 \wedge T_r\}}.$$ Now apply the lemma and rewrite the expression in a suitable way...